# Can we use algolia for geocoding related search , without uploading any data?

Tags: ios, algolia

I have just started to use algolia framework in my application.While using that Im not able to use geocoding search in it.

Very first problem that occurs is "What is licence key" with your algolia account you have ?

Then how we can add geocoding / search facility with name i.e. autocompletion feature to application ?

If any documentation you have please share.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to start playing with the Algolia Geo-search feature is probably to have a look to this step by step tutorial https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/geo-search#dependencies.

And then based on that second tutorial https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/multi-auto-complete it should be fairly easy for you to implement what you've just described.